# Account creation in web3 1.0.0

Tags: web3js, accounts

What is the difference between

```
web3.eth.accounts.create()
```

and

```
web3.eth.personal.newAccount()
```

With first invocation I'm able to create a new account. The second call throw me:

> Invalid JSON RPC response: ""